# Transition to a route on successful async Redux action

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

When I am deleting the `category` with an API call, Redux doesn't wait for all actions to complete. Sample action below:

```js
export const deleteCategory=(id)=>{
    return dispatch=>{
        const message='Category Deleted Successfully!'
        dispatch(deleteCategoryStart())
        axios.delete(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/admindashboard/categories/${id}/`)
        .then(res=>{
            dispatch(deleteCategorySuccess(message))
        }).catch(err=>{
            dispatch(deleteCategoryFailed(err))
        })
    }
}
```

My code to handle the delete:

```
handleDelete= (event) =>{
      event.preventDefault();
      this.props.deleteCategory(this.props.match.params.categoryID);
      this.props.history.push('/categories')
}
```

I am trying to delete the `category` and redirect the user to the "all categories" page. Instead, it's redirecting the user before all action dispatches are completed. The new categories page/component calls additional actions, getting all categories.

Action sequence:

[image]

Comment: Did you managed to solve the problem. I just want to know if there is any better solution than what I have been doing(approach following) this till now (as posted in my answer) in the similar situations above. Thanks in advance. :) - @MazenAhmed

Comment: @PrathapReddy sorry for my late response i handled it by redirecting upon if there is an error message or not , i did if condition between the render and the return

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript explicitly won't wait for your external process (API call) to complete. You can use `async/await` or change your code similar to below

```js
export const deleteCategory = (id) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(deleteCategoryStart());
        return axios.delete(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/admindashboard/categories/${id}/`);
    }
}
```

```js
handleDelete = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.props.deleteCategory(this.props.match.params.categoryID).then(res => {
      const message='Category Deleted Successfully!';
      this.props.dispatch(deleteCategorySuccess(message));
      this.props.history.push('/categories'); // Push to the page here
      }).catch(err => {
          this.props.dispatch(deleteCategoryFailed(err));
      });
}
```